# Hide path to image

Tags: .htaccess

I have
`<img src="/wp-content/themes/test/folder/7.jpg">`

I want to hide 'folder' and show another path:
`<img src="/wp-content/themes/test/images/7.jpg">`

I tried in .htaccess:
`RewriteEngine on`
`RewriteRule ^images/([^/]+)$ folder/$1 [L]`

But this doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You missed `wp-content/themes/test/` in rewrite path. Test example link: `your-domain.com/wp-content/themes/test/images/7.jpg` should load file from `/wp-content/themes/test/folder/7.jpg`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^wp-content\/themes\/test\/images\/(.*)$ /wp-content/themes/test/folder/$1 [L]
```